What makes iron special?
Iron is the end of the road for fission and fusion, the lowest energy nucleus.  It's also the strongest magnetic atom.  Is this coincidence, or is there a deeper connection?

Technically Nickel 62 is the most tightly bound nucleus. But ignoring that, the binding energy has to do with the nucleons configuration while magnetic behavior has to do with electron configuration, so offhand I'd say it is a coincidentally

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/961/2451

I'd argue that this question is a dupe of that given we also marked https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232875 as a dupe of that.

This question is similar to: Why is the nucleus of an Iron atom so stable?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The proposed duplicates say nothing about the magnetic properties of iron. Is it just a coincidence, or are there interesting similarities between iron's electronic shell structure and its nuclear shell structure?

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40407/is-iron-the-most-stable-element-in-the-periodic-table

Something I don't get - what is the difference between most tightly bound nuclei, and most stable nucleus?


Iron is the end of the road for fission and fusion, the lowest energy nucleus. It's also the strongest magnetic atom. Is this coincidence, or is there a deeper connection?

Well it's not exactly a coincidence, but the two things are not directly linked.
Fusion and fission are governed by the nuclear properties.
Magnetism has to do with the properties of the electronic structure of the atom.
So while the electron states are linked to the nucleus as they depend on the mass and charge of the nucleus, you would not find an obvious link by comparing e.g. the spectrum of Iron to the nuclear properties of Iron.
If I change the nuclear properties by using different isotopes of Iron, I don't get quite the same effect in any resulting change in magnetic properties, simply because the small change in mass of the nucleus has a relatively small effect on the electronic state.  Likewise, changing the energy levels of the electrons does not significantly affect the nuclear properties.
They are linked by the number of protons in the nucleus, but you'd find that hard to tell by comparing the two sets of properties.
