# Why Don't All Heavy Elements Decay into $^{62}\rm Ni$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy

I read the question [If we assume that protons don't decay, then will all matter ultimately decay into Iron-56 or into nickel-62?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15943/), but I have a different question concerning the decay that has nothing to do with quantum tunneling.

My question is this: If $^{62}\rm Ni$ has a higher binding energy than $^{56}\rm Fe$, why wouldn't all of the heaviest elements (even those man-made) decay into $^{62}\rm Ni$?

Answer (score 1):

A 235U nucleus can't just decay into  62Ni. That would violate conservation of mass-energy and conservation of charge. It *can* decay into 62Ni plus other products, e.g., by fission.

> but I have a different question concerning the decay that has nothing to do with quantum tunneling

Fission does involve tunneling.

Comment: Sorry - I never thought of fission as tunneling

Comment: I suspect a very small possibility of the decay of 62 U235 into 235 Ni62 exists, although it is unthinkably small.

Comment: @Rick: If you draw a graph of potential energy as a function of shape, as the nucleus deforms and approaches scission, you get a barrier, and the nucleus has to tunnel out through that barrier in order to fission.